# Generate signed apk Error:Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType]

Tags: android, android-resources

I have this problem when I generate signed apk:

> F:\...\app\src\main\java\com\palletdesign\clipdooni\Activity_VideoPlay.java
>   Error:Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType]

and this is
 **Activity_videoplay.java** (Error for this part of code ) :

```
position = i.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);
allArrayVideo = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_ID");
allArrayVideoCatName = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_CATNAME");
allArrayVideoCatId = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_CATID");
allArrayVideourl = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_URL");
allArrayVideoName = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_NAME");
allArrayVideoId = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_CID");
allArrayVideoDuration = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_DURATION");
allArrayVideoDesc = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_DISCRIPTION");
allArrayImageUrl = i.getStringArrayExtra("VIDEO_IMAGE_URL");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file add this code :

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    disable "ResourceType"
  }
}
```

Comment: @user2003857 you can accept the answer if it help you.